# Wordpress migration results in infinite redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, migration

I am trying to migrate a WordPress website from a hosting service with domain "A" to a new AWS EC2 instance with domain "B".

So I created a new EC2 instance with domain B directing to it, installed php, apache and mysql.
I placed the wordpress files in /var/www/html and imported the database to mysql.

This results in: when I browse to domain B I am redirected to domain A.

I notice the table "B5F_options" has the rows with "option_value" = "home" and "option_value" = "siteurl" have the A domain as "option_value".

So I updated these two rows with the B domain.

However this results in an infinite redirect loop.

So how can I finish the migration successfully?

Comment: I move WordPress sites on an almost daily basis, and in fact I'm doing one right now. I always, always, always use the [WP CLI tool](https://wp-cli.org/) to handle the database after import on the new server. The command I run is `wp search-replace "https://old.example.com" "https://new.example.com" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run`. Be very certain about the canonical protocol and domain for both sites, and don't include a trailing slash. After that runs in dry run mode (and tells you how many things it changed), remove that parameter and run it for real.

Comment: Sometimes I also run it multiple times with variations from the original such as `"http://old.example.com" "https://new.example.com"` (non-secure) and `"https://example.com" "https://new.example.com"` (missing the subdomain on the original). The destination URL should always stay the same. When you test this in your browser, do it in a private browsing window because some browsers cache 301 redirects which will drive you nuts.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas I installed wp cli and executed the command. It replaced quite a few old domain instances. However I still get infinite redirects even though I cleared my cache and tried another browser I didn't use before.

Comment: Check the wp-config.php file to see if it has a domain baked into it (it will be obvious if it does). If you see one, just comment it out, don't bother changing it, that's an old hackier way to do it.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas I look at wp-config.php and it doesn't include any domain.