# I've migrated my WP site but can't update img links

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, data-migration

I have migrated the site and all the images are in the expected folders (these are discoverable). I need to change the links from to newsite.com/ but whatever I do they're still pointing to old-site.com/.

Using Wordpress, Beaver Builder.

Things I have tried:

Ran the following query on my database:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, 'old-site.com','newsite.com'));
```

and

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid=(REPLACE (guid, 'old-site.com','newsite.com'));
```

and the following, which resulted in an error because there's no such column as meta_value

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(meta_value,'https://old-site.com/','https://newsite.com/');
```

Used Beaver Builder to re-save images individually. They appear correctly with the new url, until the page is refreshed.

Re-saved Permalinks.

Purged the SG Cache.

Cleared cache at Settings > Beaver Builder > Tools

Hard refresh. Cleared browser cache. Incognito browser.

Added the following to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://newsite.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://newsite.com/');
```

There are no posts in the database still pointing to the old url. The images are not referenced in the theme files or styles.

I have hundreds of images so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you can use the CLI, see my comments on this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69229047/231316

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm only wanting to change my hosted site, not local. Is there an option to use CLI directly on the server?

Comment: Yes if you can SSH into your server. If you don't know how to do this, I would strongly encourage learning this, it is an important skill for web development. If your server doesn't support SSH, I'd personally recommend looking for an alternative host.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, finally I was able to solve it by doing a complete migration with the plugin "WP Migrator", since then all my links are detected and I don't use any other method anymore.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Appreciate the recommendation, I'll try that next time I'm migrating to hopefully not have so many issues!

Answer (score 1):

I think first thing you need to identify the images including page is coming from cache or from user server(same-origin). Check with Chrome Developer tools.

Inspect > Network > Check you page url > check header response > server

[image]

If from cache-server like 'cloudflare' or cf-cache-status: HIT status found you need to clear the cache. It will different depending on your hosting provider or which cache you used.

If not, check on the MySQL DB again with such follwing query in each table -

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE "%old-site.com%"
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%old-site.com%"
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE guid LIKE "%old-site.com%"
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE "%old-site.com%"
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. My server wasn't caching (Apache) but the DB queries helped point me in the right direction. I used Better Search Replace to update the database. This operation caused errors yesterday but I must have done something different because it worked today.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Better Search Replace WP Plugin to search for old-site.com and replace with newsite.com. I also removed Transients using the Transients Manager plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/transients-manager/.

Check the database for any remaining references to old-site.com using the following queries on the database (thanks @lwin-ko-ko):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE "%old-site.com%"
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%old-site.com%"
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE guid LIKE "%old-site.com%"
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE "%old-site.com%"
```